# Equivalence between exact sequence of module and its induced one.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, exact-sequence

Let $X,X',X''$ be $A$-modules and denote by $\mbox{Hom}_A(X',X)$ the set of $A$-homomorphisms of $X'$ into $X$.

Proposition 2.1 in the Lang's Algebra text states the following:

A sequence 
$$
X' \xrightarrow{\lambda} X \xrightarrow{\mu} X'' \to 0
$$
is exact iff the sequence
$$
\mbox{Hom}_A(X',Y) \xleftarrow{\lambda^*} 
\mbox{Hom}_A(X,Y) \xleftarrow{\mu^*}
\mbox{Hom}_A(X'',Y) \leftarrow 0 
$$
is exact for all $Y$. where $\lambda^*(g) = g \circ \lambda$ and $\mu^*$ is defined simliarly.

I cannot prove the 'if' ($\Leftarrow$) part; quite stuck. Any help or suggestion?

What I've done so far;

I proved $\mbox{Im} \lambda \subseteq \mbox{Ker} \mu$ by drawing commute diagrams.

Comment: I think you need to add “for all $Y$” after the exact sequence of $\mathrm{Hom}$-sets. Otherwise, take $Y = 0$; then the sequence of $\mathrm{Hom}$-sets is exact, independent of what $X$, $X'$, and $X''$ are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prove exactness at $X''$ (surjectivity of $\mu$), take $Y = \mathrm{coker}(\mu)$. The canonical map $q \colon X'' \to Y$ is mapped to $0$ by $\mu^{*}$, hence was already $0$. Since $q$ is surjective, $Y = 0$.

You can deduce $\mu \circ \lambda = 0$ by taking $Y = X''$, and looking at what happens with $\mathrm{id}_{Y}$.

Finally, look at $Y = \mathrm{coker}(\lambda)$. The canonical map $q \colon X \to Y$ is mapped to $0$ by $\lambda^{*}$, hence comes from a map $f$ in $\mathrm{Hom}(X'', Y)$. In other words, $f \circ \mu = q$. In particular, ther kernel of $\mu$ is contained in the kernel of $q$ (which is the image of $\lambda$).